# asp.net forums download

Tags: asp.net, forums

I remember years ago being able to download and install the forums software used on the asp.net site.  I am not able to find it now, does anyone know if this is still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asp.net was / is?? community server: http://telligent.com/products/telligent_community/

Answer (score 2):

I like this one: http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

It is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with the software used on the ASP.NET site but this is a better forum in my opinion anyway, and done in ASP.NET MVC:
http://demos.telerik.com/mvc/